# Fast Fourier Transform Pseudocode?

Tags: math, language-agnostic, computer-science

The purpose of the following code is to convert a polynomial from coefficient representation into value representation by dividing it into its odd and even powers and then recursing on the smaller polynomials.

```
function FFT(A, w)

Input: Coefficient representation of a polynomials A(x) of degree ≤ n-1, where n 
is a power of 2w, an nth root of unity.

Output: Value representation A(w^0),...,A(w^(n-1))

if w = 1; return A(1)
express A(x) in the form A_e(x^2) and xA_o(x^2) /*where A_e are the even powers and A_o  
the odd.*/
call FFT(A_e,w^2) to evaluate A_e at even of powers of w
call FFT(A_o,w^2) to evaluate A_o at even powers of w
for j = 0 to n-1;
    compute A(w^j) = A_e(w^(2j))+w^j(A_o(w^(2j)))

return A(w^0),...,A(w^(n-1))
```

1. What is the for loop being used for?
2. Why is the pseudocode only adding the smaller polynomials, doesn't it need to subtract them too? (to calculate A(-x)). Isn't that what the algorithm completely based on? Adding *and* subtracting the smaller polynomials to reduce the points in half?*
3. Why are powers of "w" being evaluated as opposed to "x"?

**I am not a too sure if this belongs here, since the question is quite mathematical. If you feel this question is off-topic, I would appreciate it if you moved it to a site where you felt this question would be more appropriate, rather that just closing it.**

*Psuedocode was gotten from *Algorithms* by S. Dasgupta. Page 71.

Answer (score 0):

1. The loop is for recursion.
2. No need to add for negative x; the FFT transforms from time to frequency space.

Comment: Could you expand? I do not have the strongest foundation in math- what does time have to do with this and what is a frequency space? Note that I have no experience with mathematical Fourier transforms/models. This is the only experience with it. Secondly, recursion for what? Doesn't calling FFT on A_e and A_o do the recursion?

Comment: Dude, FFT is all about the math.  If you don't know it, you can't understand the algorithm.  It helps to know what a Fourier transform is - trigonometric functions, complex variables, a little calculus.  Once you have that, you need to know why the discrete algorithm is important.  Asking someone to explain it to you here, without any background, is like asking someone to tell you how to shoot a rocket to the moon without understanding physics.

Comment: I do have some knowledge in math. The book containing the question only provides some information about roots of unity, and some info about complex numbers. I assumed thats enough math to answer the question, since the book doesn't mention anything else. Could you possibly use math, limited however, while focusing on the computer science aspect while answering the question?

Comment: Use [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Thomas-H-Cormen/dp/0262033844). It explains the algorithm, why it is important, etc.

Comment: And what will that book include?  Math....can't get away from it.  *Every* discussion of FFT will assume knowledge of trig functions, calculus, series, complex variables, and Fourier transforms.